# A non-constant, increasing function $f$ such that $f(b)=\int_a^bf$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration, functions

Is there a non-constant, increasing function $f\colon A\to B$, where $A,B\subset\mathbf{R}$ such that $$f(b)=\int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm{d}x$$ for $a,b\in{A}$ with $a<b$.

Comment: If we take derivatives we get the differential equation $f'(b)=f(b)$. The solutions to this equation are the functions of the form $f(b)=Ce^{b}$. You can check now, which of them can satisfy your integral equation.

Comment: @james Can you please use some quantifiers? I'm really confused. Do you require all pairs $(a,b)$ to satify the equality or is one enough?

Comment: Since you never use $B$, just skip it - it makes thinks confusing. (Usually, when you have two sets, $A,B$, and use variables $a,b$, we expect $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.)

Comment: I think you need to be clear about whether you want $a,b$ to just be some choice of $a,b$, or whether you have one choice of $a$ and you want it hold for all $b > a$, or vice-versa you have one $b$ and want it to hold for all $a < b$, or whether you want it to hold for all choices of $a,b$ that satisfy $a < b$.  The answer depends

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\int\limits_a^b e^xdx=e^b-e^a$$

Try then to use $\,a=-\infty\,$ and get an improper (convergent, of course)  integral...

Comment: But $a=-\infty\not\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: So? The condition is that $\,A,B\subset\Bbb R\;$ and, for example, $\,A=(-\infty,\infty)\,$ makes the cut.

Comment: The question asks for $a,b\in A$. As far as I know, $-\infty$ is not an element of $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: That's true, indeed. Yet I think the generalization is not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

A non-continuous example: let $A=[-1,1]$, $a\in[-1,0]$, and $b=1$. Then set $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[-1,0)$, $1$ otherwise. It's clear that $f$ satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

*In this work we look for an answer using only the differentiable functions*

Let the equation defined by
$$f(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
so if we differentiate we find
$$f'(x)=f(x)$$
and then the necessary condition is:
$$f(x)=Ce^x$$
Now we verify if this condition is suffisant:

$$\int_a^xCe^tdt=C(e^x-e^a)=Ce^x\iff C=0\,\text{or}\ a=-\infty$$

hence we conclude that if $a=-\infty$ there's an infinity of solution and if $a\ne-\infty$ then the zero function is the only possible solution.

Comment: I disagree with the last statement; it's certainly the only differentiable solution.

Comment: Yes you're right I deal only with the differentiable functions.